# number of divisors of a composite number

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

Consider the power series $\sum_{n\ge1} a_n z^n$ where $a_n =$ number of divisors of $n^{50}$. then the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n\ge1} a_n z^n$ is

(1) 1

(2) 50

(3) $\frac 1 {50}$

(4) 0

Comment: So, what do you know about the number of divisors of $n^{50}$?

Comment: @Gerry, I see your point.

Comment: @Gerry  
if n is prime then the number of divisors of n^50 is 51, but when n is composite..?

Comment: You don't need an exact answer, just a bound good enough to tell you when the series converges.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: what is the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n\ge1}z^n$? of $\sum_{n\ge1}n^{50}z^n$?

Comment: @ Gerry 1 is the radius of convergence of  ∑n≥1zn

Comment: Yes, the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n\ge1}z^n$ is $1$. Can you work out the radius of convergence of the other sum I mention? maybe using the ratio test?